# Matlab operator ~

Tags: matlab

I understand that the ~ operator is the equivalent of ! operator from C. So I understand it in an if condition. But I don't understand what the operator ~ does here exactly.

```
function [y] = m_binary (x, pm)
y=x;
for i=1:length(x)
   r= unifrnd(0,1);
   if r<pm
      y(i)=~x(i);
   end;
end;
end
```

Comment: if x is a vector of bolean, then y(i) is the negation of x(i)

Comment: If only there were some [**documentation**](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/not.html) on this...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `~` operator in MATLAB is actually very similar to the `~` operator in C rather than the `!` operator. In C `~` is the binary ones compliment operator (see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm)) which has the effect of flipping the bits. It's more commonly known as the logical not operator which is how the [MATLAB docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/not.html) describe it. In MATLAB, instead of flipping bits it performs element-wise negation on a vector.

In your case it will simply flip the `i`th element of `x` assuming `x` is a vector of logicals. Some caveats with MATLAB though, if `x` isn't a logical, then `~` will just find all the elements of `x` that are `0`. For example `~[0 0 1 0 2]` returns `[1 1 0 1 0]` so in MATLAB `~3` will be `0` whereas in C I would guess it would return an integer (at a guess something like if three is 00000011 then ~3 would be 11111100 so `~3` might return `252` for a unit8)

Comment: I think this is a confusing use of the word 'bit`, there is no bit flipping happening in the MATLAB use case, it's more like element-wise logical negation.

Comment: "The ~ operator in MATLAB is actually very similar to the ~ operator in C rather than the ! operator." -- except your explanation says otherwise.

Comment: @CrisLuengo it is similar, but operating on different data types. In C it will treat an int as a bit array. In MATLAB it's meant to be used directly on an explicit bit array. MATLAB also will coerce non-zero integers to be logical `true` so it's not the `~` operator behaving differently but the language. The similarity is in the concept of inverting bits of a bit array.

Comment: @Dan: On each element of the array, it applies the equivalent of C's `!`. In MATLAB, `~3.4` is the same as `!3.4` in C. The documentation you link specifically says it returns a logical, which is the equivalent of C's boolean. And of course MATLAB applies the operator to each element of the array, it does that for `+` and `&` and `.*` et c.

Comment: The equivalent of C's `~` operator is [`bitcmp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitcmp.html).